# SQL Execute Task partially works

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SQL Execute Task in my SSIS template that will either TRUNCATE or CREATE based on whether the table exists but the problem I'm encountering is if the script runs in sequence w/ all the other tasks in the Control Flow, it will not create the table if it doesn't exist. If I stop the package, and execute the SQL script by itself, it works just fine. Any pointers would be appreciated.

SQL Script:

```
IF object_id('[RAW].[TABLE_NAME]') is not null
    TRUNCATE TABLE [RAW].[TABLE_NAME]; 
ELSE
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE RAW.TABLE_NAME
        (
            [Sys_ID] BIGINT NOT NULL,
            [Report_Date] DATE,
            [Ingestion_Date] DATE
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [Sys_ID] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]

        ALTER TABLE [RAW].[TABLE_NAME] ADD  DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[TABLE_SEQUENCE]) FOR [Sys_ID]    
    END
```

Comment: Are you executing it against the correct database in SSIS?

Comment: @PhilippJohannis considering it works when I run it on it's own, I would say yes. Thank you for confirming though.

Comment: Maybe there's an issue with your sessions? If you make your commands dynamic and execute will it work?

Comment: Are you executing the script within SSIS or in SQL Server Management Studio (or another GUI)? Does SSIS fail when executing this step or succeed?

Comment: @EmmanouilKaramalegos Could you elaborate on "make your commands dynamic"? Thank you

Comment: @PhilippJohannis I am executing it inside the VS SSIS designer.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the configuration and maybe of the whole flow? Also you didn't say if the execution marks the tasks as success or fails.

Answer (score 1):

This answer aims to resolve session conflicts. It is more of a suggestion than a solution..

A couple remarks first:

- There is [Primary] on the creation of the table
- You are using two different schemas dbo & raw

Regarding what I mentioned on the comment about dynamic code:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)


IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[RAW].[TABLE_NAME]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'TRUNCATE TABLE [RAW].[TABLE_NAME]'
    EXEC (@SQL)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = ' CREATE TABLE RAW.TABLE_NAME
                (
                    [Sys_ID] BIGINT NOT NULL,
            [Report_Date] DATE,
                [Ingestion_Date] DATE
            PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
            (
                [Sys_ID] ASC
            )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
            ) ON [PRIMARY]'
EXEC (@SQL)
SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [RAW].[TABLE_NAME] ADD  DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[TABLE_SEQUENCE]) FOR [Sys_ID]'
EXEC(@SQL)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who contributed to helping me resolve this issue. However, this was a major oversight on my part! I failed to set "ValidateExternalMetadata" for my OLE DB Destination to "False". The package was attempting to locate the table and failed in the event that it did not exist before reaching my SQL script to create the table.

Answer (score -1):

Change truncate to drop

IF object_id('[RAW].[TABLE_NAME]') is not null

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [RAW].[TABLE_NAME];   -->> DROP TABLE [RAW].[TABLE_NAME];
```

Comment: The Table shouldn't be dropped but truncated according to the question, or created if it doesn't exist.